# New Dataframe Column Name based on old data - issue with code

Tags: python, pandas

I had a piece of code that used to work to generate a new field based on server names truncated.
Essentially I wanted to only use the first 11 characters in a string.

This used to be

```
df['newname'] = df.(ServerName).str[:11]
```

However the source of the servername (api) has been changed so when I bring it into my data frame its actually  serverdetails:servername

When I try and change my code it has an issue with the : now in the column name so it won't execute.
I tried to do

```
df['newname'] = df.('serverdetails:ServerName').str[:11]
```

But that didn't work, I imagine its just a coding format that I haven't realised but any help would be appreciated

Comment: could you provide a minimum working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this syntax for accessing columns:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'cd'], columns=['column:name'])
>>> df['newname'] = df['column:name'].str[:1]
>>> df
  column:name newname
0          aa       a
1          ab       a
2          ac       a
3          cd       c
```